# How to create a list of dictionaries from the list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There is the list of lists, named "people": `people=[['Sara Smith', 42, 'female', 35000], ['John Lee', 25, 'male', 25000]]`
I'd like to create the list of dictionaries: 
`person=[{'name:'Sara Smith', 'age':42, 'gender':'female', 'income':35000}, {'name:'John Lee', 'age':25, 'gender':'male', 'income':25000}]`
How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
fields=['name', 'age', 'gender', 'income']
print(len(people))
for i in range(0, len(people)):
    exec("people%d = %s" % (i + 1, repr(people[i])));
    person=[]
    person.append(dict(zip(fields, people[i])))
    print(people[i])
print(person)
```

But for some reason, as a result of "print(person)" I have [{'name': 'John Lee', 'age': 25, 'gender': 'male', 'income': 25000}]. I cannot understand, why my result includes only a dictionary for people[1] in the list and maybe there are some more elegant solutions for the task

Comment: You need to move `person=[]` above the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `dict()` and `zip` `fields` into each using a list comprehension.

```
people=[['Sara Smith', 42, 'female', 35000], ['John Lee', 25, 'male', 25000]]
fields = ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'income']

dict_people = [dict(zip(fields, l)) for l in people]
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'Sara Smith', 'age': 42, 'gender': 'female', 'income': 35000}, {'name':'John Lee', 'age': 25, 'gender': 'male','income': 25000}]
```

Comment: Although by doing this you dont keep the `name`, `age`, `gender`, `income` fields. You end up with `name:age`, `gender:income`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a much cleaner way to do it

```
people=[['Sara Smith', 42, 'female', 35000], ['John Lee', 25, 'male', 25000]]
fields=['name', 'age', 'gender', 'income']
person=[]
for i in people:
    person.append(dict(zip(fields, i)))
print(person)
```

Output is:

[{'name': 'Sara Smith', 'age': 42, 'gender': 'female', 'income': 35000}, {'name': 'John Lee', 'age': 25, 'gender': 'male', 'income': 25000}]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this all with a single dictionary comprehension. I'd really really recommend avoiding using `exec` unless you absolutely need to.

Try something like this instead:

```
person_dicts = [{"name": person[0], "age": person[1], "gender": person[2], "income": person[3]} for person in people]
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Sara Smith', 'age': 42, 'gender': 'female', 'income': 35000}, {'name': 'John Lee', 'age': 25, 'gender': 'male', 'income': 25000}]
```

Although this assumes your people list's sublist for a single person is always ordered the same way.

Edit:

If you don't want to use comprehensions you can always just use a for loop too.

```
person_dicts = []
for person in people:
    person_dicts.append({"name": person[0], "age": person[1], "gender": person[2], "income": person[3]})
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for ideas.
Finally I solve it by

`pers_dicts = [dict(zip(fields, person)) for person in people]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with zip as mentioned before :

```py
people=[['Sara Smith', 42, 'female', 35000], ['John Lee', 25, 'male', 25000]]
fields=['name', 'age', 'gender', 'income']

persons = []
for person in people:
    tmp_dict = {}
    for key, value in zip(fields, person):
        tmp_dict[key] = value
    persons.append(tmp_dict)
```

Results :

```py
[
  {'age': 42, 'gender': 'female', 'income': 35000, 'name': 'Sara Smith'},
  {'age': 25, 'gender': 'male', 'income': 25000, 'name': 'John Lee'},
]
```